# unix bash rename --backup=numbered from abc.txt.~1~ to abc~1~.txt

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am looking for a way to process my hughmungus amount of nested & numbered backups without changing structure or meta-data.
After a bit of research I have a follow up to [unix mv --backup=numbered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529779/unix-mv-backup-numbered) ...

#### How to change the following `mv`,`sed` command to not treat `.~x~` as a file ending ?

i.e.

- How to remove the "." before "~" ?
- How to apply it to non-ending-type files?

###### [`given answer that almost works`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61954533)

```sh
swap_file_extension_and_backup_number ()
{
IFS=$'\n'
for y in $(ls $1)
do
    mv $1/`echo $y | sed 's/ /\\ /g'` $1/`echo "$y" | sed 's/\(\.[^~]\{3\}\)\(\.~[0-9]\{1,2\}~\)$/\2\1/g'`
done
}
```

which is called like this `swap_file_extension_and_backup_number /folder_path/` and would rename like that:

```
/folder_path/imfine.jpg
/folder_path/sadly_i_dont_get_changed.~1~
/folder_path/def.txt.~1~
```

to

```
/folder_path/iamfine.jpg
/folder_path/sadly_i_dont_get_changed.~1~
/folder_path/def.~1~.txt
```

but should create

```
/folder_path/iamfine.jpg
/folder_path/sadly_i_dont_get_changed~1~
/folder_path/def~1~.txt
```

<sup>In short: I am unable to process the sed/regex line. Please don't lapidate me.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
swap_file_extension_and_backup_number ()
{
IFS=$'\n'
for y in $(ls $1)
do
        mv $1/`echo $y | sed 's/ /\\ /g'` $1/` echo "$y" | sed 's/\(\.[^~]\{3\}\)\?\(\.\)\(~[0-9]\{1,2\}~\)$/\3\1/g'`
done
}
```

See Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XxF4eo/1)

Comment: Just quickly tried on macOS. Using `-r` results in an error. Will try soon on Linux. <br> However, I think I realized what you did and tried to adapt the regex to ... `'s/\(\.[^~]\{3\}\)\(\.\)\(~[0-9]\{1,2\}~\)$/\3\1/g'` which works and achieves point 1, but not 2 (`name.~1~`). So I guess it's fine for any file with a file type ending and hence for all of my media.

Comment: I updated the answer without `-r` check it and let me know if there is an error, I also add a regex demo to see the result and captured group.

Comment: Well, `-r` was just my local problem, maybe not on another machine. Thank you, though! The regex demo is great, and the preview looks like the desired result. But sadly it doesn't behave like that; on macOS.

Comment: I tested in a Linux machine and it's worked, no idea about mac os. :(

Comment: Ok, after a bit of try and error I found [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345604/why-is-my-regex-not-working-using-sed-in-bash-script-on-mac-osx) and tried `-E` instead of `-r`. With your cleaned up version the part  ...`?(\.)`... works and produces the desired result also on macOS. Might have been wasted time though, as it will have to do on Ubuntu. You could revert it and keep the current regex. Not sure whether `?(\.)?` is necessary, but that can be left as an exercise to the reader ;).

Comment: This `?(\.)?` is wrong (probably my mistake if I wrote before). The question mark matches zero or one time, so when we put a `?` in front of this part: `(\.[^~]\{3\}\)` it means this part can match or not(kinda optional) so this part can not match or exactly matched once. In case `/folder_path/def.txt.~1~`  this part matches the `.txt` part and in case `/folder_path/sadly_i_dont_get_changed.~1~` this does not match with this part of the pattern, (rest of pattern match this). BTW current regex version is the correct one (also you can add  `-r` and unescape the characters in regex)